# jQuery .wrapAll() Issue

Tags: jquery

I am using my CMS to output list items, and then I am using .wrapAll() to wrap the list items in a ul based on their class. This is to basically group them, because I can't do it on the server side with my CMS.

But it is wrapping list items that have the same class into one unordered list. How can I get around this?

jQuery

```
$('.week_7').wrapAll('<ul class="devotionals"/>');
$('.week_6').wrapAll('<ul class="devotionals"/>');
$('.week_5').wrapAll('<ul class="devotionals"/>');
$('.week_4').wrapAll('<ul class="devotionals"/>');
$('.week_3').wrapAll('<ul class="devotionals"/>');
$('.week_2').wrapAll('<ul class="devotionals"/>');
$('.week_1').wrapAll('<ul class="devotionals"/>');
```

HTML: Before jQuery

```
<li class="week_1">Day 1</li>
<li class="week_1">Day 2</li>
<li class="week_1">Day 3</li>
<li class="week_1">Day 4</li>
<li class="week_1">Day 5</li>
<li class="week_2">Day 1</li>
<li class="week_2">Day 2</li>
<li class="week_2">Day 3</li>
<li class="week_2">Day 4</li>
<li class="week_2">Day 5</li>
```

This continues to continue list items with week 3 through 7.

HTML: After jQuery

```
<ul>
    <li class="week_1">Day 1</li>
    <li class="week_1">Day 2</li>
    <li class="week_1">Day 3</li>
    <li class="week_1">Day 4</li>
    <li class="week_1">Day 5</li>
    <li class="week_1">Day 1</li>
    <li class="week_1">Day 2</li>
    <li class="week_1">Day 3</li>
    <li class="week_1">Day 4</li>
    <li class="week_1">Day 5</li>
    <li class="week_2">Day 1</li>
    <li class="week_2">Day 2</li>
    <li class="week_2">Day 3</li>
    <li class="week_2">Day 4</li>
    <li class="week_2">Day 5</li>
    <li class="week_2">Day 1</li>
    <li class="week_2">Day 2</li>
    <li class="week_2">Day 3</li>
    <li class="week_2">Day 4</li>
    <li class="week_2">Day 5</li>
</ul>
```

HTML: How it should render

```
<ul>
    <li class="week_1">Day 1</li>
    <li class="week_1">Day 2</li>
    <li class="week_1">Day 3</li>
    <li class="week_1">Day 4</li>
    <li class="week_1">Day 5</li>
    <li class="week_2">Day 1</li>
    <li class="week_2">Day 2</li>
    <li class="week_2">Day 3</li>
    <li class="week_2">Day 4</li>
    <li class="week_2">Day 5</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li class="week_1">Day 1</li>
    <li class="week_1">Day 2</li>
    <li class="week_1">Day 3</li>
    <li class="week_1">Day 4</li>
    <li class="week_1">Day 5</li>
    <li class="week_2">Day 1</li>
    <li class="week_2">Day 2</li>
    <li class="week_2">Day 3</li>
    <li class="week_2">Day 4</li>
    <li class="week_2">Day 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This isn't not an EE specific question so I'm migrating it to the StackOverflow site

Answer (score 1):

Add an [end()](http://api.jquery.com/end/) statement at the end of each line.
e.g.

```
$('.week_1').wrapAll('<ul class="devotionals"/>').end();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but adding end(); doesn't do anything.

Comment: Tested this on your markup and it worked perfectly for me, can you post your code here?